# Descriptive statistics in my native language in R

Tags: r

Regardless of R! variables:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", 'pl_PL.UTF-8')
Sys.setenv(LANG = "pl_PL.UTF-8")
```

when I use function such as summary, output is given in English, not in my native language (Polish).

Currently I use gsub function to replace appropriate words. However, I wonder if there is any automated way of translating those messages?

Comment: Have you seen this translated automatically anywhere? The `summary.default` source code sets these names in english and doesn't seem to check for the locale: `names(qq) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", 
            "Max.")`

Comment: No, but...correct me if I am wrong, but other packages have such possibility/translated packages. If there's no such feature in R!, I'm eager to participate in adding such feature (from you comment I guess it shouldn't be very difficult).

Comment: Have your read the manual regarding internationalization? https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Internationalization and looked up the teams that are already working on this: http://developer.r-project.org/TranslationTeams.html